# Stopword does not want to be deleted in python

Tags: python, pandas, stop-words

I've imported my `stopword.txt` file in python as:

```
stopword = [line.rstrip() for line in open('gdrive/My Drive/stopword.txt')]
```

and tried to remove stopwords from my pandas dataframe column:

```
train['text'] = [i for i in train['text'].str.split() if i not in stopword]
```

The code is running well, but the stopwords are still there. What's wrong with my code?

Comment: Can you tell us what `stopword.txt` looks like, and what `train['text']` initially contains?

Comment: This looks fine, so you need to provide a [mre] with example input, desired output, and actual output. The dataframe might be irrelevant. Try factoring it out and just use a list instead. BTW welcome to SO! Check out [ask] if you want more advice.

Comment: @GreenCloakGuy stopword list from [link](https://github.com/masdevid/ID-Stopwords/blob/master/id.stopwords.02.01.2016.txt) and train['text'] from twit Twitterscraper.

Comment: Oops, I just noticed the `.split()`. That's the problem. I'll write an answer.

Answer (score 0):

Using `.split()` turns each `i` into a list. So you just need to add a nested loop to iterate over `i`:

```
train['text'] = [i for i in train['text'].str.split() if not any(w in stopword for w in i)]
```

---

BTW, if you're using `stopword` only for this, make it a set. Sets are designed for fast membership tests, while lists aren't.

```
with open('gdrive/My Drive/stopword.txt') as file:
    stopword = {line.rstrip() for line in file}
```

Comment: It's produce error like this:
->  train['txt'] = [i for i in train['txt'].str.split() if not any(w in stopword for w in i)]
TypeError: 'float' object is not iterable
And how to make it a set?

Comment: @Newbie You're indexing the wrong column. `train['txt']` should be `train['text']`.

Comment: @Newbie Added how to make it a set

Comment: @Newbie Huh, I don't know where the floats are coming from, but then I only know the bare minimum of Pandas myself. Could you post a [mre] in the question?

Comment: ----> 2 train['txt'] = [i for i in train['txt'].str.split() if not any(w in stopword for w in i)]

3 frames
/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/pandas/core/internals/construction.py in sanitize_index(data, index, copy)
    609 
    610     if len(data) != len(index):
--> 611         raise ValueError("Length of values does not match length of index")
    612 
    613     if isinstance(data, ABCIndexClass) and not copy:

ValueError: Length of values does not match length of index

Answer (score 0):

The answer is

```
train['txt'] = train['txt'].apply(lambda x: [item for item in x.split() if item not in stopword])
```

Comment: Yup, i forgot to remove it.  I copied from other stack overflow answer. Thanks for helping me.